# Sitecore Azure Continuous Delivery

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I'm new to this topic - Continuous Delivery,

We already have **Azure Web App** Site is Deployed to Production and Running,and We do have the license for **TDS** and currently Using **Sitecore 8.2 Update 3**
We are planning to **Implement Automated Deployment**. Since its a sitecore project we want to have sitecore changes are also gets reflected as part of Continuous Delivery.
Can someone guide me whats the best Approach for Continuous Delivery by considering the below Software

- Azure WebApp
- Sitecore 8.2 Update 3
- TDS(Team Development for sitecore)
- GIT

Comment: You could always use Azure ARM Powershell tools to package up your custom site Read on
[Sitecore Azure Quick Start Templates](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/Sitecore%208.2.3) See blog with details on deployment [here](http://blog.baslijten.com/sitecore-8-2-update-1-azure-deployments-arm-web-deploy-and-the-sitecore-azure-toolkit/)

Comment: hi @D0cNet,  we already have the sitecore web app running in azure environment. i'm expecting an answer for the continuous Integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer received from Devops Guy(karthick)
The best practice would be like

- Below are the steps
- You can have your feature (web) projects and TDS solutions in Git
- Use VSTS/TFS or any tool you prefer, to build and get the nuget packages ( web projects & . update for TDS) using nuspec's
- For web apps, have deployment slot methodology.
- Use Octopus for deployment, once the package ks pushed to Octopus Feed from your build tool
- Everytime delete and recreate the deployment slot ( avoid junk files retained)
- Prefer Sitecore clean deployment ( have a Sitecore base package and deploy your solution files on top of that)
- Deploy the changes to the deployment slot
- Validate the functionality with the deployment slot URL
- Swap the deployment slot with the production slot (main web app slot)